# How to merge objects when calling SetState in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

In my component, I have a state that looks like this:

```
  class MainClass 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form: {
        startDate:"1/11/2020", 
        endDate:"5/11/2020", 
        ....
     },
    };
  }
```

I have a function that updates both the start and end date and another that updates the form

```
  handleFormChanges = targets => {
    targets.forEach(function (target) {
      this.setState({
        form: { ...this.state.form, [target.name]: target.value },
      });     
     });
  };
  

..... 


updateDate(startDate, endDate) {
const newStartDate = {name:"startDate", value:startDate.value}
const newEndDate = {name:"endDate", value:endDate.value}
this.handleFormChanges([newStartDate, newEndDate])
}
```

So I realized that calling setState in a loop is a code smell and not how react works. How can I combine the target array so that I only need to call setState once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to accumulate the `targets` in one go

Edit: to work with both single object and array of objects, you could wrap `targets` in square bracket `[]` and then `flat()`

```js
this.setState({
  form: {
    ...this.state.form,
    ...[targets].flat().reduce(
      (acc, target) => ({ ...acc, [target.name]: target.value }),
      {}
    ),
  },
})
```

Comment: what does acc mean in this scenario? does it mean accumulated?

Comment: @lost9123193 yeah, it's the accumulator that store accumulated value through each iteration, you could see more in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: i want to use this solution but it looks like it removes the other fields in this.state.form

Comment: @lost9123193 basically this approach is similar to your solution, but instead of `setState` with `target.length` time(s), it grab all the `{ [target.name]: target.value }` into an object and destruct that

Comment: there was a bug in my code. This works and makes sense thanks!

Comment: can I ask a quick question, I know this current method accepts an array but is there a way to accept both an array and a single object?

Comment: @lost9123193 there is a simple trick to work with both cases, you could wrap it into square bracket `[]` and then `flat()`,  `[targets].flat().reduce...`

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a wrong idea because you can miss some data and cause additional rendering for each iteration.

Main idea to use setState once per function. Also you don't need to use handleFormChanges, much better to add values by keys)

```
updateDate(startDate, endDate) {

 this.setState({
        form: { 
        ...this.state.form, 
       "startDate": startDate.value,
        endDate: endDate.value
          },
      });    
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make this work with a method like handleChange instead of being hardcoded in?

Comment: Take a look to @hgb123 answer) He wrote that you need)

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like

```js
const newObj={};
 targets.forEach(function (target) {
 
        newObj[target.name]=target.value,
       
     });
this.setState({...this.state.form,...newObj})
```